# jQuery detect refreshing of the page when ajax is in progress and stop reload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a script ajax which is launched every 32 seconds sending an ajax request :

```
setInterval(function() {
    var dt = new Date();
    var time = dt.getHours() + ":" + dt.getMinutes() + ":" + dt.getSeconds();
    console.time("debut ajax");
    $.getJSON('http://127.0.0.1:<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; ?>/order/get_orders', function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        if(jQuery.type(data) === "array") {
            var id = data[0].id; var starter = data[0].starter; var meal = data[0].meal; var dessert = data[0].dessert; var expenses = data[0].expenses;
            var iduser = data[0].log_by; var date = data[0].date;
            var server= "<?php echo $this->config->item('server_url');  ?>index.php/account/updateExternal?";
            $.ajax({
                url: server+"&callback=?",
                data: "balance="+expenses+"&starter="+starter+"&meal="+meal+"&dessert="+dessert+"&date="+date+"&id_user="+iduser+"&place=client2",
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (resp) { 
                    var myObj = $.parseJSON(resp); 
                    $.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1:<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; ?>/order/update_log?id="+id+"&balance="+myObj.expenses+"&starter="+myObj.starter+"&meal="+myObj.meal+"&dessert="+myObj.dessert+"&id_user="+myObj.id_user, function(data) {

                    }); 
                },
                error: function(e) {
                    //alert('Error: '+e);
                 }  
            });
        }       
    });
    console.timeEnd("fin ajax");
}, 32 * 1000);
```

During this ajax request I need to prevent or stop the page from refreshing. How to do it ?

```
// Reload the page if the input is onfocusout for some reasons
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function(){
        $("#barcode").focus();
        $('#mtsg').html('Staff Canteen Software<br />Veuillez placer votre badge pour identification');
    });
    $( "#barcode" ).focusout(function() {
        $(location).attr('href', "http://127.0.0.1:<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']; ?>/");
      });
});
///
```

Comment: The browser window is mine and I control it and I will refresh it when I want. You might be able to use the `onBeforeUnload` event to stop it from refreshing, but then I and many other potential users will leave the site and never return

Comment: you can do with `window.onbeforeunload` witch prompt user to reload or no, there is no other ways.

Comment: You can't prevent a visitor from refreshing, leaving or closing your website. This would be considdered browser hijacking. Even `onBeforeUnload` has some serious restrictions to its use due to the amount of abuse of this function in the past. What I would do is create a custom event that triggers `onBeforeUnload` that prompts the visitor asking if he's sure he wants to refresh / leave / close due to the ajax request. Then enable this event upon triggering the ajax request and disable it again on success.

Comment: The page reload is executed by javascript